# Mat-Select dropdown detached from select element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular and trying to set up a dropdown with mat-select. For some reason, when you click on the element to open the options, they appear after other page content on the left as seen in below image (this is when I select "Class"):

[image: Mat-select inputs not aligned to select option]

All `position`/`display` are default so I am not sure what else could be affecting its positioning. Here is the relevant code snippets

**HTML**

```
<div class="character-detail-header">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Class:</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="characterClass" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let charClass of classes" [value]="charClass">{{charClass}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error>
              <span *ngIf="!characterForm.get('characterClass').valid && characterForm.get('characterClass').touched">Please enter Class</span>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
    <!-- Continued -->
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
mat-label {
  color: black;
  width: 25%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  float: left;
}

mat-select,
input {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
.character-name-header {
      width: 30%;
      float: left;
      border: 1px solid black;

      mat-form-field {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    .character-detail-header {
      padding: 1rem;
      width: 60%;
      float: right;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;

      mat-form-field {
        width: 28%;
        height: 2rem;
        margin: 0 1rem;
      }
    }
```

Comment: The screenshot looks really off, it looks like the css/scss coming with angular material is missing. How did you add AM to the project?

Comment: @AlexBiro I used `ng add @angular/material`

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled material and the problem is still there...

Comment: I would still look into the styles. I would probably create a new empty angular project, with the same versions, and the same styles config (css/scss/etc) as the problematic project, create a commit there, and add AM, and check whether the changes it makes are present in the problematic project.

Comment: Your styling is causing the problems - `float` for one. Delete your styling and start over, making one change at a time so that you can know when you break something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Late) UPDATE**: need to restart angular server in order to see changes.